# How Can I Scale My Calculator App to Any Device Size?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm making a calculator app in Android Studio. I want to make it scale-able with any device, and I'm using a Restraint Layout parent with horizontal Linear Layouts inside. How do I do this? I can get the width to scale using match parent but not sure how to scale button height.

Comment: Use the nested Linear Layout with layout_weight attribute and use the fill parent for height

Comment: Use Constraint Layouts. They have a flat hierarchy, can scale very easily. Takes a bit learning curve but they are very good.

Comment: You did not provide any code, we don't have answer that fits for all case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using scaleType: fitStart from Attributes dropdown menu in Android Studio.